# Multiple Sensors connected using I2C with different addresses software approach

Tags: pi-4, i2c, input-device

I'm using a Rapberry Pi 4 Model B with 4 same I2C sensors. I want to get real-time data from them, but my knowledge of I2C is limited. I know that I can connect them, using different buses, but same address, and I was wondering if I could connect them using different addresses also. I know that this is possible with a multiplexer, but I don't know if there is any software approach.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: `my knowledge of I2C is limited` ... look for tutorials ... SparkFun has one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do this in software ***if*** your hardware provides the ability to change its i2c address. This is typically accomplished through the use of *pullup* resistors on the hardware which can be connected (or disconnected) by switches, solder bridges, etc. After all, `i2c` is a ***bus*** - not a point-to-point connection :)

Check your hardware documentation, or you can share your device specs, and we can check if you're unsure on how to do this.

###### EDIT:

From the [URL you provided in your comment](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-2510.html), I found this:

> The sensor has 32 modifiable I2C addresses, ...

***Therefore :*** Yes, you can put all 4 of your sensors on the same i2c bus.

***Correction :*** All GPIO have pullups, BUT all but a very few (maybe 2?) of these pullups are only enabled in software. If you will make reference to this commonly-used [RPi Pinout reference](https://pinout.xyz/#), then click on [GPIO2](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin3_gpio2#), you will find this explanatory note:

> SDA includes a fixed, 1.8 kΩ pull-up to 3.3v, which means this pin is not suitable for use as a general purpose IO where no pull-up resistor is desired.

GPIO2 and GPIO3 are the *default* i2c bus on RPi4B, aka `i2c1`. You will need to **enable** this bus before using it. It may be enabled using either the `raspi-config` utility, or from adding a line to the file `/boot/config.txt`:

```
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
```

In closing: I've gone a bit beyond your original question now, and so any follow-on questions on this topic should probably be submitted as a new question. Hope this [helped](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thank you for the response. As I said before, I use a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (2018) and the sensors I use are [these](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-2510.html). They have the exact same module (I have test it personally) and the difference is only in the probe. I know that Raspberry Pi has integrated pullup resistors for every GPIO (correct me if I'm wrong). I have enough of the rest electronics (resistors, cables, breadboard etc). I don't know how to check the Pi specifically for its hardware abilities.

Comment: @ExhaustedCProgrammer: Please see the edits.

Comment: Thank you. I think that I understand what to do. One last question here: am I supposed to give these addresses to every device? Or are they given by default?

Comment: @ExhaustedCProgrammer: On any given `i2c` bus, each device must have a unique address. I can't tell you definitively what the default address(es) are - that should be covered in the device documentation. However, I'd ***guess*** that all the devices come from the mfr with the same address - so you'll need to change the address on all but one of them.